# Removing the smell of cannabis left by previous owners

Tags: smell

Having recently purchased a house which was previously used to grow a "commercial" amount of cannabis I'm struggling to remove the smell. It seems to be engrained in to every surface, hard or soft. How would you approach the task of deodorising the property?

UPDATE: The house has since exploded, problem solved.

Comment: In some localities a structure that was used for such purposes may be condemned since it's very difficult and expensive if not downright impossible to remove the odor.  You may want to consult with a professional restoration service but I suspect you'll discover that the only real fix is removing all the contaminated surfaces and replacing them.

Comment: I'd be more worried about the associated moisture causing mold issues. I hope you got a thorough inspection done.

Comment: @jwh20 no, you're thinking of *meth*. Meth is a horrible, illegal chemical that destroys lives and irrevocably contaminates houses with toxic materials.  Also, meth has a well-rated cable TV show about its dealers.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  Meth presents its own environmental problems and odors are the least of them.

Comment: Check and see if you have recourse with the seller. This probably will be a legal issue.

Comment: Your update states the house exploded.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes certainly. A gas explosion destroyed the premises, no one was harmed as everyone was out at work and the building was empty #nearmiss

Comment: That's... one way of handling the situation... Glad everyone is OK!

Answer (score 2):

Grow some other strong smelling plants, lavender, eucalyptus etc. In fact many many non odoriferous plants in a space will help to "clean" the air.

It will dissipate.

Air ionization machine.

Citrus based cleaners.

Baking soda sprinkled on the carpets.

Comment: I see images of teenagers hastily unloading entire cans of Fabreze as the parents roll up the driveway unexpectedly.

Comment: Plan on repainting EVERYTHING with an odor killing primer.

Answer (score 2):

I have worked at a company that cleans up after a fire for some time. To deodorize they use a machine that vaporized large amounts of cleaning agent. I would find such a company and try to rent one of those machines. If it can get rid of the smell of fire, I would assume it can get rid of any smell.